# Codeigniter: Routes only visible when entering /index segments

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-url

I'm working on my first project with codeigniter 2.0 and have a bit of a problem.
On my localhost (a MAMP installation) everything works fine with the routes. Only when i add a copy on my domain, change the base url and other necessary settings like my database settings it works fine for like 99%. I can't access my other controllers directly without adding the /index route. For example when i want to visit the http://my_domain.com/work it'll open the 404 error page but when i enter ttp://my_domain.com/work/index it works fine. Does someone know a setting i have to change for the online version? The Htaccess files are identical.

CHeers in advance.

Comment: do you have this line in your config.php file? : `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

Comment: I had, but edited it into: $config['index_page'] = ''; this didn't made any difference. It works locally and doesn't work online.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled in Apache?

Comment: Yes this is my .htaccess file:
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution. I just checked the routes.php file in my config where i added a route for every controller. I just removed these and only my default_controller route is left. Now it works fine. Just a codeigniter newbie issue.

Thanks anyways for the help @Hibiscus and @BigFatBaby

Answer (score 1):

I sorted my problem by setting the following line as my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

It'll rewrite anything after the /index.php/blaha to /blaha.